# How to execute code randomly and in a different order each time in python

Tags: python, selenium

So this question is based off some a random project I was making. Basically this project has a number of smaller scripts inside of it, and what I want to be able to do is play then randomly or only play sometimes.

So here is a example of what I mean (because if I post all the scripts it would get messy). Lets say I have 5 scripts that are all part of a bigger project. Something like this.

```
Project 1 which has 5 scripts inside which are:
   Script 1
   Script 2
   Script 3
   Script 4 
   Script 5
```

So what I want to be able to do is randomly play these scripts in a different order. So for the first run I want to have Script 1 play, then Script 2 then Script 5, but skip Script 3 and 4. For the next run I want to be able to Play Script 3 and Script 5 but skip the others. Is this possible? Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you guys for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of is to randomly generate a permutation sequence :

```
files=['script1.py','script2.py','script3.py']
n=len(files)
sequence=list(np.random.permutation(n)) #generate a random permuation
```

To skip some files :

```
skip=np.random.randint(n)
for i in range(skip):
    num_to_remove=np.random.randint(n)
    if(num_to_remove in sequence):
        sequence.remove(num_to_remove)
```

Execute the remaining

```
for i in sequence:
    exec(open(files[i]).read()) #execute file
```

Comment: This can be simplified with the random shuffle function, which shuffles a list in place i.e. `import random` / `random.shuffle(files)`

Comment: Thanks for your reponse Sruthi! I got the error that 'name np is not defined' and googled the solution. The fix was to import numpy as np. That fixed that error, however I am now getting the error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'remove'. Any ideas?

Comment: @KunwarSodhi I made the changes : `sequence=list(np.random.permutation(n))`

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do random selections of a random number of scripts, e.g. say you want to run between `2` and `5` scripts for 10 runs then you can simply do:

```
import random

scripts = ['script1', 'script2', 'script3', 'script4', 'script5']

number_of_runs = 10
for run in range(number_of_runs):
    for script in random.sample(scripts, k=random.randint(2, 5)):
        print("Run {}: {}".format(run, script))
        # execute script
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried your response and I got invalid syntax for the line that is "for script in random.sample(scripts, k=random.randint(2, 5):" I believed it was that it needed 2 parentheses so I tried this: for script in random.sample(scripts, k=random.randint(2, 5)): however it gives me a Sample larger than population or its negative error. Any ideas why?

Comment: It does, fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionnary with the key being an integer and the value the name of your script.
Then use random.randint(1, number_of_scripts) to get a random index for your dictionary and then run
os.system(dict[random.randint(1, number_of_scripts)-1])